# Найти сумму элементов массива не кратных 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан целочисленный массив из 10 элементов.

Диапазон значений  элементов массива от -50 до 49.

Найти сумму элементов массива не кратных 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(array):
    sum_ = 0

    for i in array:
        if i % 7:
            sum_ += i

    return sum_

my_array = [3, 2, 10, 7, -21, -2, 1, 14, 20, 21]

vz = solution(my_array)
print(vz)
```